# React URL param redirect

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, url-parameters

I am currently working with **react** and **react-router** and I'm building a page that shows details of a certain item that gets its data from an API when the page mounts. The fetch method requires the item's `id` so I'm using `match.params.id` to get the value for the fetch method. I also am using the **slug** package in the backend to show the title for that item in URL format alongside the `id`. I want users to be able to type in the URL with the slug title and not have to worry about typing the `id` in order to be directed to the page with the correct data.

For example, clicking on the item on the UI will make the URL look like this: `localhost:3000/the-title-slug/123456`.
You have to actually click on the item on the UI to get the URL to have the id but I want to make things simpler for the user and make it so that if they only type the slug title: `localhost:3000/the-slug-title`, it will redirect to the correct URL with that slug and id.

Any ideas on how this could be done? Kind of like if you type `googel.com` it corrects the typo and directs you to `google.com`. Any help figuring this out would be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your backend must to have the API method to get correct item by misspelled slug.
like:

```
requestData: the-slug-title
responseData: the-title-slug, 123456
```

and then your component have to handle wrong url

```
componentDidMount() {
  const { params } = this.props.match;

  const respose = await fetch({ ... })

  this.setState({ id: response.id, slug: response.slug });
}

render() {
  const { params } = this.props.match;

  return this.state.id && this.state.slug && (this.state.id !== params.id || this.state.slug !== params.slug) && <Redirect to={`/${this.state.slug}/${this.state.id}`} />
}
```